# As a data container, what are the main differences between vector and list

Tags: clojure

Say we need a list of numbers, there are two definitions:

```
(def vector1 [1 2 3])
(def list2 '(1 2 3))
```

So what are the main differences?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `[1 2 3]` is a [vector](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Vectors%20%28IPersistentVector%29), whereas `'(1 2 3)` is a [list](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Lists%20%28IPersistentList%29). There are different performance characteristics of these two data structures.

Vectors provide quick, indexed random access to its elements `(v 34)` returns element of vector `v` at index `34` in `O(1)` time. On the other hand it is generally more expensive to modify vectors.

Lists are easy to modify at head and/or tail (depending on implementation), but provide linear access to elements: `(nth (list 1 2 3 4 5) 3)` requires sequential scan of the list.

For more information on the performance tradeoffs you can google "vector vs. list performance" or something similar.

[FOLLOW-UP]

Ok, lets get into some more detail. First of all *vectors* and *lists* are concepts that are not specific to Clojure. Along with *maps*, *queues*, etc., they are abstract types of collections of data. Algorithms operating on data are defined in terms of those abstractions. *Vectors* and *lists* are **defined** by the behavior that I briefly described above (i.e. something *is* a vector *if* it has size, you can access its elements by and index in constant time etc.).

Clojure, as any other language, wants to fulfill those expectations when providing data structures that are called this way. If you'll look at the [basic implementation of `nth` in `vector`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java#L110), you'll see a call to `arrayFor` method which has the complexity of *O(log<sub>32</sub>N)* and a lookup in Java array which is *O(1)*.

Why can we say that `(v 34)` is in fact *O(1)*? Because the maximum value of *log<sub>32</sub>* for a Java `int` is around **7**. This means that random access to a vector is *de facto* constant time.

In summary, the main difference between `vectors` and `lists` really *is* the performance characteristics. Additionally, as Jeremy Heiler points out, in Clojure there are logical differences in behaviour, i.e. with respect to growing the collection with [`conj`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/conj).

Comment: Hi Pawel, seems that the complexity is not `O(1)`. Cause `(my-vec idx)` is translated to `(nth my-vec idx)`.

Comment: @xiaowl `nth` is a function that works on vectors and lists, on vectors it provides quick access.

Comment: FYI, rather than *de facto constant time*, the terminology I've traditionally seen in the context of Clojure is *effectively constant time*.

Answer (score 10):

There are two main differences between lists and vectors.

1. Lists logically grow at the head, while vectors logically grow on the tail. You can see this in action when using the `conj` function. It will grow the collection according to the type of collection given to it. While you can grow collections on either side, it is performant to do so in this way.
2. In order to retrieve the nth item in a list, the list needs to be traversed from the head. Vectors, on the other hand, are not traversed and return the nth item in O(1). (It really is O(log32n) but that is due to how the collections are implemented as persistent collections.)

Answer (score 4):

vector assess time is not O(1) it's log32N

Vectors (IPersistentVector)
A Vector is a collection of values indexed by contiguous integers. Vectors support access to items by index in log32N hops. count is O(1). conj puts the item at the end of the vector. Vectors also support rseq, which returns the items in reverse order. Vectors implement IFn, for invoke() of one argument, which they presume is an index and look up in themselves as if by nth, i.e. vectors are functions of their indices.

Comment: Do you mean `log2N`?. But according to the cheatsheet of clojure, `(my-vec idx) → ( nth my-vec idx)`, the `(my-vec idx)` is translated to a `nth` call. And, from doc of `nth`, it is `O(N)` to access an element.

Comment: @xiaowl, Read the documentation a little more carefully. The O(n) time refers to the nth item of a sequence, which must be traversed due to the requirements of the abstraction. For vectors, it is, for all intensive purposes, O(1).

Answer (score 4):

- A vector holds all data items in adjacent areas of memory, making
  transfer of the entire vector easy and insertion or deletion of items
  expensive when compared with lists.
- Lists hold items is disjoint areas of memory, making transfer of the
  entire list expensive but insertion and deletion of individual items
  relatively cheap.
- Classic vectors are also fixed in size, and limited to N items, while
  lists can dynamically grow and shrink.
- Vectors also offer indexed access to the element items. Lists don't.
  The classic vector's predecessor is an array.
- Modern implementations of vectors often aim at providing similar
  characteristic, but the underlying data structure may in fact be a
  list or a hash, and those vectors typically support dynamic
  re-sizing.