# Is list or vector faster for accessing two most recent entries (in Clojure)?

Tags: clojure

This is sort of a follow-up for [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504236/as-a-data-container-what-are-the-main-differences-between-vector-and-list)

Say we need to access the two most recently inserted elements in a collection. Would a list or a vector be faster for that operation?

Are these the fastest options?

```
; for list
(def l '(3 2 1))
(peek l)
=> 3
(peek (pop l))
=> 2

; for vector
(def v [1 2 3])
(peek v)
=> 3
(peek (pop v))
=> 2
```

Or would it be faster to do something like:

```
(v (- (count v) 1))
=> 3
(v (- (count v) 2))
=> 2
```

I would greatly appreciate an explanation as to how this situation is correctly analyzed. This is for my first game and Clojure program, which is why I'm concerned about performance. :) The reason I'm not packing the two values together is to avoid unpacking/mapping them as the whole collection has a use as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'd be bound to use either list or vector, I would go with vector because `subvec` is very fast.

```
(let [a (vec (take 100000 (range)))]
    (time (subvec a (- (count a) 2))))
"Elapsed time: 0.045805 msecs"
=> [99998 99999]
```

But it is not clear what are you trying to do. Maybe there is a better data structure for your case.

Comment: I'm using `seesaw` and passing the collection to `seesaw.graphics/draw` to draw a series of lines. `draw` takes `shape` and `style` as args, so the collection as it stands consists of alternating `seesaw.graphics/polygon` objects and maps describing styles. Should I add this to the question (thought I'd keep it more general)?

Comment: `draw` uses `first`, `second`, `next` when processing its arguments, so it might be that a list would be better. You could time both. How much pairs (line+style) do you have?

Comment: At least tens of thousands, possibly over 100k.

Comment: A mere loop over a 100K vector  takes 11 msecs on my computer and 9 msecs for a list.

Comment: As @akond imlies, don't waste time worring about microscopic differences in vectors & lists.  Besides, anything drawing on the screen is going to take (literally) 1000x more time than fiddling stuff in memory.

Comment: That could well be some of the best advice a fledgling game maker can get, certainly one like me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Clojure's vector uses the out-of-tree tail optimization, which basically means until it fills up, the latest node in the structure sits in up in the object header instead of being put down in the tree.  So you should be seeing constant time lookup for the `n % 32` highest-indexed elements in a tree of `n` elements.

For a *list* in the strictest sence, getting to the second element would always involve following the chain through element 1 (two steps), but if any of the operations you do make an implicit call to `seq`, a cache gets introduced and it becomes somewhat less clear.